# In VBScript, how can I retrieve the first element of an InstancesOf collection?

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I'm writing a VBScript that should identify the OS details. I found an exemple here using InstancesOf Win32_Operating system, but instead of the foreach loop from the sample, I only want to address the first occurence, so I did:

```
Set SystemSet = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf ("Win32_OperatingSystem")
Set System = SystemSet.Item(0)
```

Also tried `Set System = SystemSet(0)`, but each time I have a generic failure error message (Echec générique in french).

How can I achieve this so I can then compare the `System.Caption` string?

Comment: Did you tried like that : `Set SystemSet = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf ("Win32_OperatingSystem") : For Each System In SystemSet : sys = System.Caption : Next : WScript.Echo sys
`

Comment: I would try with `GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem").ItemIndex(0).Caption` (I think it is only available from Windows Vista) or encapsulate the `For Each` loop handling of the collection in a helper function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GetObject("winmgmts:")` returns a `SWbemServices` object. According to the documentation for the `SWbemServices` object the `InstanceOf()` method:

> <sup>From [`SWbemServices.InstancesOf` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/swbemservices-instancesof)</sup>
> creates an enumerator that returns the instances of a specified class according to the user-specified selection criteria.

The idea of an enumerator is to enumerate over a collection of objects this lends itself to the VBScript [`For Each` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/tywtbxd0(v=vs.84)) for iterating over an enumerator.

A simple example would be;

```
Dim swbemInstances, swbemInstance
Set swbemInstances = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each swbemInstance In swbemInstances
  WScript.Echo swbemInstance.Caption
Next
```

You can access an instance directly from the enumerator using the `ItemIndex` method which as the documentation says;

> <sup>From [`SWbemObjectSet.ItemIndex` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/swbemobjectset-itemindex)</sup>
> returns the `SWbemObject` associated with the specified index into the collection. The index indicates the position of the element within the collection. Collection numbering starts at zero.

---

> **Note:** Interesting point the documentation actually cites the  `Win32_OperatingSystem` class as an example where you likely want to retrieve only one instance and explains how to use `ItemIndex` to facilitate it.
>
> <sup>From [`SWbemObjectSet.ItemIndex` method - Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/swbemobjectset-itemindex)</sup>
> Only one instance of [Win32_OperatingSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-operatingsystem) exists for each operating system installation. Creating the GetObject path to obtain the single instance is awkward so scripts normally enumerate **Win32_OperatingSystem** even though only one instance is available. The following VBScript code example shows how to use the **ItemIndex** method to get to the one **Win32_OperatingSystem** without using a **For Each** loop.

Something like;

```
Dim swbemInstance
Set swbemInstance = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem").ItemIndex(0)
WScript.Echo swbemInstance.Caption
```

<sup>*Also mentioned in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408713/in-vbscript-how-can-i-retrieve-the-first-element-of-an-instancesof-collection#comment110378679_62408713)*</sup>