# Find All Possible Screen Resolutions for All Monitors via WMI

Tags: vbscript, wmi, autohotkey, screen-resolution, wmi-query

How to do so in a WMI query?

Attempted to use the query first directly on the [VideoModeDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmicoreprov/videomodedescriptor) class, however this is accessible only when instanced. So tried [InstancesOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/swbemservices-instancesof) as in the following AutoHotkey snippet:

```
Enabled := ComObjError(1)
wmi := ComObjGet("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" A_ComputerName "\root\wmi")
Instances := wmi.InstancesOf("VideoModeDescriptor", 1)
  For Instance In Instances
  msgbox % Instance.CompositePolarityType ; e.g. test first element
```

No success, however there is a possibility it can be used in conjunction with `GetObject` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62411065/2128797).
So the other option of querying [WmiMonitorListedSupportedSourceModes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmicoreprov/wmimonitorlistedsupportedsourcemodes) was the better approach,- but how to obtain raw resolution data?

Answer (score 0):

The complete solution for AHK is:

```
wmi := ComObjGet("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" A_ComputerName "\root\wmi")
for monitor in wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT NumOfMonitorSourceModes, MonitorSourceModes FROM WmiMonitorListedSupportedSourceModes WHERE Active=TRUE",,wbemFlagForwardOnly := 32)
{
modes := ""
Loop, % monitor.NumOfMonitorSourceModes - 1
modes .= monitor.MonitorSourceModes[A_Index - 1].HorizontalActivePixels . " " . monitor.MonitorSourceModes[A_Index - 1].HorizontalImageSize . " "
msgbox % monitor.InstanceName . "`n" . modes
```

Interestingly, the standard `For Each` *key, value* iteration yields blank for `monitor`, and the code fails for `root\cimv2` with an invalid class error. `ExecQuery` is generous enough to provide `InstanceName` even though it is not specified in the original query.
The following vbscript code only yields the preferred resolution, but it's easy to apply the above technique for all of them:

```
strComputer = "."

strQuery = "SELECT PreferredMonitorSourceModeIndex, NumOfMonitorSourceModes, MonitorSourceModes " & _
       "FROM WmiMonitorListedSupportedSourceModes"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\ROOT\WMI")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery(strQuery, , 48)

For Each objItem In colItems
    intIndex = objItem.PreferredMonitorSourceModeIndex
    msgbox("NumOfMonitorSourceModes: " & objItem.NumOfMonitorSourceModes & _
Replace("\nInstanceName: ", "\n", vbLf) & objItem.InstanceName & _
Replace("\nHorizontal: ", "\n", vbLF) & objItem.MonitorSourceModes(intIndex).HorizontalActivePixels & _
Replace("\nVertical: ", "\n", vbLF) & objItem.MonitorSourceModes(objIintIndex).VerticalActivePixels)
Next
```